# Trying to fix TypeError: freqRolls() missing 1 required positional argument: 'sides' python

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am a new python programmer and I am creating a program that will randomly generate dice program that will choose how many sides of a dice it is going to use, so I can then, later on, figure out how to print the frequency of how many times the dice landed on that number. I am getting a "TypeError: freqRolls() missing 1 required positional argument: 'sides' error when trying to print out how many sides the dice has starting at 1 and going up to the number of sides the program decided to use.

```
import random
listRolls = []

#Randomly choose the number of sides of dice between 6 and 12
#Print out 'Will be using: x sides' variable = numSides
def main() :
    global numSides
    global numRolls

    numSides = sides()
    numRolls = rolls()

    rollDice()

    listPrint()

    freqRolls()

def rolls() :
    x = (random.randint(200, 500))
    print('Ran for: %s rounds' %(x))
    return x

def sides():
    y = (random.randint(6, 12))
    print('Will be using: %s sides' %(y))
    return y

def freqRolls(sides):
    for i in range(1, len(sides)) :
        print("%2d: %4d" % (i, sides[i]))

#  Face value of die based on each roll (numRolls = number of times die is 
thrown).
#  numSides = number of faces)
def rollDice():     
    i = 0
    while (i < numRolls):
        x = (random.randint(1, numSides))
        listRolls.append(x)
#            print (x)   
        i = i + 1
#        print ('Done')

def listPrint():
   for i, item in enumerate(listRolls):
      if (i+1)%13 == 0:
        print(item)
   else:
      print(item,end=', ')





main()
```

Comment: You defined `freqRolls` to take one parameter `sides` but you didn't provide it when calling `freqRolls`.

Comment: Okay, I just tried to provide it when calling 'freqRolls' and it gave me the error that 'sides()' does not have a len

Comment: `freqRolls` uses `len(sides)` which asks `sides` for a length it seemed not to provide.

Comment: If you are not familiar enough with Python you should start with the [Python tutorial](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you declared the freqrolls() function in this piece of code

```
def freqRolls(sides):
    for i in range(1, len(sides)) :
        print("%2d: %4d" % (i, sides[i]))
```

the "sides" is an argument, it means that the function expects a value and will call it "sides" only inside the function. To your function work, you need to pass this value in the moment you call it, like this:

```
 freqRolls(numSides)
```